# zlib compress2 returning Z_STREAM_ERROR

Tags: c++, zlib

```
char buffer[12] = {"Testing! 12"};

unsigned long compressedSize;
char* compressed = compress(buffer, 12, &compressedSize);

...

char* compress(char* buffer, unsigned long size, unsigned long* compressedSize)
{
    Bytef* inBuffer = reinterpret_cast<Bytef*>(buffer);
    uLong inSize = static_cast<uLong>(size);

    Bytef* outBuffer = 0;
    uLong outBufferSize = compressBound(inSize);

    int error = compress2(outBuffer, &outBufferSize, inBuffer, inSize, 6);

    if(error != Z_OK)
    {
        switch(error)
        {
            case Z_MEM_ERROR:
                std::cerr << "Memory error!" << std::endl;
                break;

            case Z_BUF_ERROR:
                std::cerr << "Buffer error!" << std::endl;
                break;

            default:
                std::cerr << "Unknown error: " << error << std::endl;
                break;
        }

        return 0;
    }

    *compressedSize = static_cast<unsigned long>(outBufferSize);

    return reinterpret_cast<char*>(outBuffer);
}
```

I hit 'Unknown error: -2' which turns out to be ZLIB_STREAM_ERROR. I can't figure out the problem. All the variables seem to be correct.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your `outBuffer` is a NULL pointer. You cannot pass a NULL pointer as the output buffer to compress2 , compress2 needs some space to store the compressed data, so allocate a buffer that's compressBound(inSize) big. It's evident from the prototype of compression2 that you can't have compres2 allocate and "return" such a buffer back to you.

Edit, as the actual error at this point is Z_STREAM_ERROR , it's because you passed in an invalid level.

> compress2 returns Z_OK if success,
>   Z_MEM_ERROR if there was not enough
>   memory, Z_BUF_ERROR if there was not
>   enough room in the output buffer,
>   Z_STREAM_ERROR if the level parameter
>   is invalid.

You should use one of these levels:

```
#define Z_NO_COMPRESSION         0
#define Z_BEST_SPEED             1
#define Z_BEST_COMPRESSION       9
#define Z_DEFAULT_COMPRESSION  (-1)
```

Comment: @Jookia right, I was reading a NetBSD manpage. As you're using compressBound, you're ok. You just need to allocate a buffer that's compressBound(inSize) big, and pass that in.

Answer (score 0):

Your `outBuffer` must be like `Bytef outBuffer[50];` or other size.